# Environment variable in Valet

Tags: nginx, environment-variables, laravel-valet

I am using default installation of Valet (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet).

I have small experience with nginx, therefore I can't locate where should I store envvars for Valet.

For apache it would be quite easy - /etc/apache2/envvars

As a temporary solution on PHP, index.php, I use `putenv('APP_ENV=dev');` but I would like to do this globally without touching index file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I find this post when I am looking for an answer, it will be easier for me if I leave a note for my self here.

Since I installed nginx using brew, nginx config is located in `/usr/local/etc/nginx`, and environment variables are already set in `fastcgi_params` file.

Append to file

`/usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`

a new line, for example

`fastcgi_param APP_ENV  dev;`

If you don't want to set this environment variable globally, it can be overwritten for each site config in `~/.valet/Nginx/site.dev` between `location ~ \.php$ {` closure.